# How to estimate the approximate total memory usage when loading a large data into Python

Tags: python, memory-management, operating-system, large-language-model, llama

I'm trying to model the memory usage of LLAMA2 model. I tried to load the model data 12.55GB in Python and did a memory profiling using process.memory_info().rss. But it turned out it's using ~13.4GB memory after loading the model. I am curious what's the extra overhead here just by loading this data torch.load('.pth', map_location='cpu'). Also a more general question how to model other memory overheads in python such as importing libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You write the file in memory to .txt or .csv and use os.stat() to get this information.

For example:

file_name = "/Users/pankaj/abcdef.txt"

file_stats = os.stat(file_name)